# Django: serve admin static files with whitenoise and site's files from S3

Tags: django, amazon-s3

I have a working Django site where I've been using whitenoise to serve static files.
I've then switched to S3 storage for both site static and media. And it works really well.

I have one problem with this setup though: collecting the admin static files (select2, tinyMCE, etc) takes lots of times and regularly fails in Heroku.

So here's my ideal scenario:

- keep everything as is BUT
- DO NOT upload the admin static files to S3 (during collectsatic) and serve them from the app server using whitenoise

So how do I achieve that?

Here's the relevant excerpt from my settings file

```
ENVIRONMENT = os.environ.get('DJANGO_ENVIRONMENT', 'dev')
IS_PROD = ENVIRONMENT == 'production'
IS_DEV = not IS_PROD

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = bool(os.environ.get('DJANGO_DEBUG', IS_DEV))

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images) and media

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '.static'

if IS_PROD:
    AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('S3_BUCKET', '')
    AWS_S3_REGION_NAME = os.environ.get('S3_REGION', '')
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('S3_KEY_ID', '')
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('S3_SECRET', '')
    AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = f'{AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME}.s3.amazonaws.com'
    AWS_S3_OBJECT_PARAMETERS = {
        'Expires': 'Thu, 31 Dec 2100 20:00:00 GMT',
        'CacheControl': 'max-age=94608000',
    }
    STATICFILES_LOCATION = 'static'
    STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.StaticStorage'
    MEDIAFILES_LOCATION = 'media'
    DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'custom_storages.MediaStorage'
    MEDIA_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/{MEDIAFILES_LOCATION}/'
    TINYMCE_JS_URL = f'https://{AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN}/static/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js'
else:
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = '.media'


STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```